# How to pipe grep and keep headers?

Tags: grep, head

In the example below, I have the right selection, but not the headers, and conversely. How can I have both?

```
$ ps aux | grep 'gpart'
erwann    200603  0.0  0.0   2608    72 pts/3    S    12:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/gparted
root      200608  0.0  0.0   2608  1056 pts/3    S    12:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/gparted
root      200693  0.0  0.0   2608    68 pts/3    S    12:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit /usr/sbin/gpartedbin
root      200700  1.9  0.2 264960 18620 pts/3    SLl  12:57   8:31 /usr/sbin/gpartedbin
root      202327 99.8  0.0   2520    64 pts/3    R    13:36 400:07 gpart -s 512 /dev/sdc
erwann    214723  0.0  0.0   9032   716 pts/4    S+   20:17   0:00 grep --color=auto gpart
$ ps aux | tee >(head -n1) >(grep 'gpart') > /dev/null
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

Comment: By headers, do you mean the line `USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND`?

Comment: You can use `ps -E` (for using extended regular expression).
For example: `ps aux | grep -E '(gpart|PID)'`

Comment: @NasirRiley, yes, how else would you call it?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon, so obvious I couldn't see it. Still I'm interested in the `tee` approach if at all feasible.

Comment: @Erwann using `tee` the output will be almost repetitive because will display twice the text. The first output will be for using `ps aux | tee`  and the second output will be for using the `grep`. In this case the first output will have more text than the second.

Comment: What do you want be shown using the `tee` command?

Answer (score 3):

Given you want to search for the fixed string `gpart` you can use a multiple match variant of `grep` to pick out matching lines as well as the first line itself:

```
ps aux | grep -E '^USER|[g]part'
```

Alternatively, a solution using `awk` that outputs the first line and any lines matching the pattern:

```
ps aux | awk 'NR==1 || /[g]part/'
```

In both cases the first character of `gpart` is in square brackets because this prevents `grep` or `awk` from matching itself. (Square brackets in a Regular Expression that contain a single character are effectively a no-op that represents just the single character itself.)

Example (based on the output from `ps` shown in your question)

```
ps aux | grep -E '^USER|[g]part'
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
erwann    200603  0.0  0.0   2608    72 pts/3    S    12:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/gparted
root      200608  0.0  0.0   2608  1056 pts/3    S    12:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/gparted
root      200693  0.0  0.0   2608    68 pts/3    S    12:57   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/udisks2/udisks2-inhibit /usr/sbin/gpartedbin
root      200700  1.9  0.2 264960 18620 pts/3    SLl  12:57   8:31 /usr/sbin/gpartedbin
root      202327 99.8  0.0   2520    64 pts/3    R    13:36 400:07 gpart -s 512 /dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 1):

If an exact match for the actual command being run (i.e. `/proc/PID/comm` rather than `/proc/PID/cmdline` on linux) is OK, try `ps`'s `-C` option.  For example:

```
ps u -C gpart
```

From `man ps`:

> `-C cmdlist`
>
> Select by command name.  This selects the processes whose executable name
> is given in cmdlist. NOTE: The command name is not the same as the command
> line. Previous versions of procps and the kernel truncated this command
> name to 15 characters. This limitation is no longer present in both. If you
> depended on matching only 15 characters, you may no longer get a match.

This will show the headers and the details for the `gpart` program but not the `gparted` programs, similar to the following (which is accurate but synthetic output partially copy-pasted from your question because I'm not actually running `gpart` on my system).

```
$ ps u -C gpart
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      202327 99.8  0.0   2520    64 pts/3    R    13:36 400:07 gpart -s 512 /dev/sdc
```

BTW, `cmdlist` can be a single command name or a comma-separated list of command names. e.g. `ps u -C gpart,gparted`.

---

Also BTW, you can combine this with other `ps` options.  e.g. if all you wanted was the PID of the `gpart` process:

```
ps ho pid -C gpart
```

`h` suppresses the header, `o pid` outputs only the PID.

or even:

```
GPART_PID=$(ps ho pid -C gpart)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean both of those lines, then any of the following:

```
ps aux | egrep "^USER.*COMMAND|gpart"

px aux | grep -E "^USER.*COMMAND|gpart"

ps aux | awk '/^USER.*COMMAND/ || /gpart/'
```

If you don't want to match the lines containing the command itself:

```
ps aux | egrep "^USER.*COMMAND|[g]part"

px aux | grep -E "^USER.*COMMAND|[g]part"

ps aux | awk '/^USER.*COMMAND/ || /[g]part/'
```

The first two commands in each series use `grep` to return any lines with the "header" and any others with the string `gpart` and the last uses `awk` to do the same.

There isn't any reason to use the command with `tee` as the others do the same and are less complex.